# Show results only when the specific string in a cell is found and only if last character is a letter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently I am working with a spreadsheet where I have to collect addresses of UK business Directors. Some of the directors have multiple addresses. UK zip code consist of two segment and I have to ignore the address where the first segment of zip code starts with W1 , SW1, EC1, EC2, EC3 & EC4 and ends with character not number because those are generally industrial address. For example Please check the following addresses where the addresses starts with W1 , SW1, EC1, EC2, EC3 & EC4 and ends with letter and I have to ignore collecting those.

```
3RD FLOOR 207 REGENT STREET, LONDON, W1B 3HH
42, CHARTERHOUSE SQUARE, LONDON EC1, EC1M 6EU
5, WESTMINSTER GARDENS, LONDON, MARSHAM STREET, SW1P 4JA
160, QUEEN VICTORIA STREET, LONDON, EC4V 4QQ
THE BROADGATE TOWER 20, PRIMROSE STREET, LONDON, EC2A 2RS
BAKERS' HALL 9, HARP LANE, LONDON, EC3R 6DP
```

Also please take note the zip codes of W11,W12 W13 and so on are not prohibited and same thing applies for the SW1, EC1, EC2, EC3 & EC4.

Now as we are working on the bulk data, its impossible to notice the zip codes when collecting the address. So I have tried with combination of various formula to highlight the first segment of those mentioned zip codes in a separate column using just right after pasting the address. In this way I can see the prohibited zip codes right after pasting the address. Although I am not successful cracking on it but I was close of it. I am just sharing the thing I have tried and looking for a compact solution from you guys.

First of I have created a separate column E where it will show the first segment of the zip code when I will paste the addresses in the column D. Here is the code which I have used:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(" "&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(D2)," ",REPT(" ",60)),120),60))
```

Next I have tried to show only those values which starts with W1 , SW1, EC1, EC2, EC3 & EC4 and ends with a letter. So I have created another column F and create the formula for "SW1"

```
=IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(E2,1)))), IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SW1",E2)), LEFT(E2,3), ""),"")
```

So if I have to check for W1 , EC1, EC2, EC3 & EC4, I have to create 5 more columns with the same formula where just have to change the value of search function. This lead me to 6 extra columns and I want a compact formula for savings the space because I generally split the browser and execl in a way that's why I can copy and paste data on the spreadsheet without minimizing the spreadsheet. This saves me a lots of time. But creating six more column will make my work more time consuming as I have to check all six columns for those zip codes.

Question - 1:

I want to ask, is there any way to make a compact formula for showing my desired result in a single column only?

Question - 2:

We also have to ignore the addresses which consist the words "floor","house" & "airport". I have tried the below formula for single query:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Floor",D2)), "Floor", "")
```

Is there any possibilities combing all required formula and show the result in one column?

Update regarding Question - 1:

I have tried to combine using some other formula to show the required result. But comes up with showing only those zip code which starts with W1 , SW1, EC1, EC2, EC3 & EC4 but can't modify it to restrict those results also where the last character is a number. Here is the code:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("W1",(LEFT(E2,2)),1))=TRUE,LEFT(E2,2)&IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(E2,1)))), RIGHT(E2,1),""),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("SW1",E2,1))=TRUE,LEFT(E2,3)&IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(E2,1)))), RIGHT(E2,1),""),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("EC1",E2,1))=TRUE,LEFT(E2,3)&IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(E2,1)))), RIGHT(E2,1),""),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("EC2",E2,1))=TRUE,LEFT(E2,3)&IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(E2,1)))), RIGHT(E2,1),""),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("EC3",E2,1))=TRUE,LEFT(E2,3)&IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(E2,1)))), RIGHT(E2,1),""),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("EC4",E2,1))=TRUE,LEFT(E2,3)&IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(E2,1)))), RIGHT(E2,1),""),""))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formula in column E could combine the *last character is not a number* with the parse of the first section of the postal code with something like the following.

```
=IF(ISERROR(--RIGHT(A2)), TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(A2, 8)), 4)), "")
```

That makes the parsing dependent on a British postal code being either 7 or 8 characters wide with the first section being either 3 or 4 characters. The 'wandering' space is either picked up and trimmed off or not picked up at all depending on the length.

With column Y listing the prefixes of the postal codes to be ignored and column Z (in any worksheet) devoted to a cross-reference list of exceptions like the following:

[image: Postal Code Exceptions Cross-Reference table]

Note that each of the entries in the Ignore list and the Exceptions list all carry the wildcard asterisk as a suffix. This is necessary to deal with staggered lengths of the comparisons to be made.

The formula used for a Conditional Formatting Rule for A2:E999 would be,

```
=AND(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($E2, $Y$2:$Y$7)), NOT(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($C2, $Z$2:$Z$4))))
```

This resolves TRUE for any postal that should be ignored and is not in the exception list.

The cross-reference tables of ignores and exceptions may benefit from becoming a named range for easy reference. You could use a dynamic range definition for the *Applies to:* of something like:

```
=Sheet1!$Y$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$Y:$Y, MATCH("zzz", Sheet1!$Y:$Y))
=Sheet1!$Z$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$Z:$Z, MATCH("zzz", Sheet1!$Z:$Z))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I didn't get any clue to solve the issue. Can you please elaborate your solution in brief. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formula to tell you whether the first word after the last comma ends with a number.

```
=ISNUMBER(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",REPT(" ",LEN(B1))),LEN(B1))),SEARCH(" ",TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",REPT(" ",LEN(B1))),LEN(B1))))-1))))
```